# Python: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable : imaplib

Tags: python, gmail-imap

This is covered extensively in SO, so I apologize in advance ...however, I've gone through the posts and can't get this to work.

**GOALS**
Want to get email from gmail that match certain criteria, save the attachments, then delete them.

**ISSUE**
So, I can get everything to work except deleting the emails. It deletes a few then I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "get_overdues.py", line 22,
>   in 
>       email_body = data[0][1] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

Every time I run it it deletes more emails then exits with the same error. This has to run on a cronjob and can't be babysat.

What am I doing wrong?

```
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login(user,word)
m.select("INBOX")

searchString = "(SUBJECT \"Daily Mail Notices\")"

resp, items = m.search(None,searchString)
items = items[0].split()

for emailid in items:
    print emailid
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")
    email_body = data[0][1]
    mail = email.message_from_string(email_body)

    if mail.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
        continue

    print "["+mail["From"]+"] :" + mail["Subject"] + mail["Date"]

    sub_dir = re.sub('[,:\- ]','', mail["Date"])

    for part in mail.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue

        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue

        message_dir = os.path.join(dump_dir, sub_dir)

        if not os.path.exists(message_dir):
            os.makedirs(message_dir)

        filename = part.get_filename()

        counter = 1 
        if not filename:
            filename = 'overdues-%s' % counter
            counter += 1

        att_path = os.path.join(dump_dir, message_dir, filename)

        if not os.path.isfile(att_path) :
            fp = open(att_path, 'wb')
            fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            fp.close()

    m.store(emailid, '+FLAGS', r'(\Deleted)')
    m.expunge()

m.close()
m.logout()
```

Comment: The error is clearly telling you that either data or data[0] is None, so that seems like an obvious place to look. Maybe that's true for empty messages? At any rate, without debugging what's being returning (e.g., log resp when data is None) and/or figuring out which message it fails on, you'll never be able to solve this.

Comment: I think it may be failing on forwards with attachments. Isn't a forward a three part message with 2 attachments? First the attached message, then the attachment from the original message. I'll test this and report back.

Comment: Any time you're working with "unknown" / possibly ill-formatted data, [`try: \ except:`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) is your friend.  I've found this especially true when using Python's IMAP with Gmail.

Comment: Thanks jedwards. Checking that out.

Comment: So, I would wrap the store exchange part at the bottom with the "try/except"? That's where the hangup is.

Comment: @Bubnoff In general, you put the `try`/`except` exactly there where you know where to proceed when something goes wrong.

Comment: `try/except` isn't going to completely save you here--it'll suppress the error, but what it won't do is actually deal with the issue.  So for example, if the email you're trying to delete throws an error, `try/except` will simply make it skip it, rather than actually deal with it, unless you figure out what's wrong and provide additional code to fix it.

Comment: jdotjdot89 right. In the except handler, you should use some means to log the exception and all local variables. That should be enough for you to figure out the relevant message as well. Extract the full message with your favorite tool, note anything unique about it, and post it along with the exception and local variables, and you'll get a lot more help.

Comment: I will give that a shot. The interesting thing is that these notices should all be identical given that they are sent by a script.

Comment: I'm going to try rewriting parts of this today as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is clearly with `fetch`:

```
resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")
email_body = data[0][1]
```

It's returning a NoneType for either `data` or, less likely, for `data[0]`, and `None` obviously isn't subscriptable.  You may want to double check the results of `m.fetch` and see if it's coming the form you expect it to.

This is probably because this email was deleted (and not expunged).

Comment: The messages are automated so they're the same. Very strange